# Prevent underflow when adding two logarithms

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, numerical-methods

I am using the addition in log space equation described on the Wikipedia [log probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability) article, but I am getting underflow when computing the exp of very large, negative, logarithms. As a result, my program crashes.

Example inputs are `a = -2` and `b = -1033.4391885529124`.

My code, implemented straight from the Wikipedia article, looks like this:

```
double log_sum(double a, double b)
{
  double min_ab = std::min(a, b);
  a = std::max(a, b);
  b = min_ab;
  if (isinf(a) && isinf(b)) {
    return -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
  } else if (isinf(a)) {
    return b;
  } else if (isinf(b)) {
    return a;
  } else {
    return a + log2(1 + exp2(b - a));
  }
}
```

I've come up with the following ideas, but can't decide which is best:

- Check for out-of-range inputs before evaluation.
- Disable (somehow) the exception, and flush or clamp the output after evaluation
- Implement custom log and exp functions that do not throw exceptions and automatically flush or clamp the results.
- Some other ways?

Additionally, I'd be interested to know what effect the choice of the logarithm base has on the computation. I chose base two because I believed that other log bases would be calculated from `log_n(x) = log_2(x) / log_2(n)`, and would suffer from precision loss due to the division. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you care to have a > b? I don't see this in your code. Also the wikipedia page suggests to use log1p which you do not (I don't know of an equivalent in base 2 though).

Comment: I was advised to make this change. Please see updated code. I get incorrect results when using log1p and expm1.

Comment: Can't reproduce. How does your program crash? exp: `If a range error occurs due to underflow, the correct result (after rounding) is returned.`

Comment: Thanks, I had floating-point exceptions enabled, which was causing the problem. I have accepted your informative answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp:

> For IEEE-compatible type double, overflow is guaranteed if 709.8 < arg, and underflow is guaranteed if arg < -708.4

So you can't prevent an underflow. However:

> If a range error occurs due to underflow, the correct result (after rounding) is returned.

So there shouldn't be any program crash - "just" a loss of precision.

However, notice that

```
1 + exp(n)
```

will loose precision much sooner, i.e. already at n = -53. This is because the next representable number after `1.0` is `1.0 + 2^-52`.

So loss of precision due to `exp` is far less than the precision lost when adding `1.0 + exp(...)`

Comment: @TruthSerum - ok, so I misunderstood. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is accurately computing the expression `log(1+exp(x))` without intermediate under/overflow. Fortunately, Martin Maechler (one of the R core developers) details how to do it in [section 3 of this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/log1mexp-note.pdf).

He uses natural base functions: it should be possible to translate it to base-2 by appropriately scaling the functions, but it uses the `log1p` function in one part, and I'm not aware of any math library which supplies a base-2 variant.

The choice of base is unlikely to have any effect on accuracy (or performance), and most reasonable math libraries are able to give sub 1-ulp guarantees for both functions (i.e. you will have one of the two floating point values closest to the exact answer). A pretty common approach is to break up the floating point number into its base-2 exponent `k` and significand `1+f`, such that `1/sqrt(2) < 1+f < sqrt(2)`, and then use a polynomial approximation to compute `log(1+f)`: due to some mathematical quirks (basically, the fact that the 2nd term of the Taylor series can be represented exactly) it turns out to be more accurate to do this in the natural base rather than base-2, so a typical implementation will look like:

```
log(x) = k*log2 + p(f)
log2(x) = k + p(f)*invlog2
```

(e.g. see [log](https://github.com/JuliaLang/openlibm/blob/e2fc5dd2f86f1e1dc47e8fa153b6a7b776d53ab5/src/e_log.c#L136) and [log2](https://github.com/JuliaLang/openlibm/blob/e2fc5dd2f86f1e1dc47e8fa153b6a7b776d53ab5/src/e_log2.c#L102-L110) in openlibm), so there is no real benefit to using one over the other.